# How to cut/paste file path in Mac os file open dialog?

Tags: macos, cut-and-paste

Pressing CMD-SHIFT-G opens a "Go to the folder" dialog.  But it is not possible to  paste the path into the text area.

I have verified the path is in the clipboard - it pastes properly in other apps. I tried Edit | paste  and Command-V  and Control-V and whatever else i could think of.  No dice.

The menu items are working fine: i can even go to the "View clipboard" and it works as shown in the screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If copy-pasting into the *Go to folder* dialog fails, try restarting Finder.

You can do it by running `killall Finder` in a Terminal window, or holding <kbd>alt</kbd> while right-clicking the Finder icon and choosing *Relaunch*.

Comment: just tried that - hey it may even have worked.  I am unsure because the problem may have been initiated by Intellij - which although a v good IDE has tons of bug -including this one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it's like this, but I have the same issue - say I've located a file or folder I want to open in the Finder, and done right-click, "Copy  as pathname", then I want to open it in an open dialog somewhere else - I do `cmd+shift+g` to "Go to folder", and `cmd+v` does nothing. But, Edit->Paste *does* work for me, and so does right-click, paste - try right-click, paste, works for me on Mojave.